# Want a .bat file that will delete a folder once a program has ended

Tags: windows, security, batch-file

My reason for needing this is for security purposes at a job. I am trying to remote into a customer's computer and run diagnostic software, but the issue is that the customer can end the remote session at anytime and keep my software. Is there a way to delete the software if the remote access service is stopped? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an easy way. You can start the programm with the batchfile itself. But you don't start it with "yourprogram.exe" in the batchfile, you start it with "START /wait yourprogram.exe"... then in the next line of your batch you just "del yourprogram.exe". with start /wait the batch waites till yourprogram.exe is closed and then continues with the delete command.

```
START /wait yourprogram.exe
del yourprogram.exe
```

But be aware that your customer still can keep a copy of a software. if its on his computer once, you cant be 100% sure he has no other way to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

if you do NOT want to start your program using the batch file:

```
@echo off
set opened=0
:loop 
if "%opened%" == "0" (
tasklist | find "yourprogram.exe"
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (set "opened=1") else (goto loop)
) else (
tasklist | find "yourprogram.exe"
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" (goto delete) else (goto loop)
)
:delete 
cd your\folder
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (goto del) else (goto error)
:del 
del *.*
cd ..\
rd yourdirectory
goto :eof
:error 
echo cannot find specified folder
```

this code deletes the specified folder when `yourprogram.exe` starts  **and** closes.
**i recommend you using `echo nul> afile.txt` and then `del afile.txt`
so the user cannot "undelete" your deleted file**, but i dont know how to apply it to all files in a folder, maybe you know?

and i recommend to use `attrib +H path\to\folder` to hide your folder. 
(replace `yourprogram.exe` with your program name, `your\folder` by the path to the directory you want to delete and `yourdirectory` by your directory name)